# Checking if the class exists on Page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check if a class exists using jquery. But something is not going well!
for example here's an HTML

```
<div id="door">
  <!-- change this class to something else to test -->
  <div class="test alfa">
    <h1>Class "Test" Does Exist</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I check that the class test exists

I'm trying the following if statement by not working for some reason. it may be something wrong with my code that I can't spot for some reason!

```
if ($('test')[0]) {
    $('h1').show();
} else {
  $('h1').text('Class "Test" Does NOT Exist');
}
```

I would appreciate it if you can test this for me or let me know what's going wrong with the above statement!?

Comment: `$('test')` is missing `.` for class

Comment: And perhaps you know can use `$('.test').length` instead of `$('test')[0]`

Comment: You can use hasClass from Jquery if you know where it is. Have a look at the following link it can help you https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/   I find that useful.

Comment: Depending your real use case, I guess you haven't  to use any js/jQuery but just CSS would be enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a dot to the test class

```
if ($('.test')[0]) {
    $('h1').show();
} else {
  $('h1').text('Class "Test" Does NOT Exist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a "." :

```
if ($('.test')[0]) {
    $('h1').show();
} else {
  $('h1').text('Class "Test" Does NOT Exist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot putting `.` on selector

```js
if ($('.test')[0]) {
    $('h1').show();
} else {
  $('h1').text('Class "Test" Does NOT Exist');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="door">
  <!-- change this class to something else to test -->
  <div class="test alfa">
    <h1>Class "Test" Does Exist</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```